# Can I apply a patent for logos?

Tags: patentability, logos

I just designed some logos for my own company. I'm wondering if I can apply a patent for those logos, and put copyrights on them?

Appreciate it!

Comment: Design patent is valid for 14 years only. A trademark can be indefinite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Design patents and copyrights are two different methods of protecting intellectual property. My guess is that for company logos copyright is more appropriate.

Comment: Yes, the copyright is what I meant. So do I have to apply for a copyright with some organizations or the logos are protected with copyright once they're created?

Comment: I am not a lawyer. I believe you get copyright automatically, but you can get a registered copyright which is probably of value for a corporate logo. Try Googling registered copyright.

Answer (score -1):

If its your own logo design, there is no doubt that you want someone else to plagiarise it.

either you go for patent or trademark, I suggest you get it done at your earliest.

Comment: You might want to elaborate what kind of patent a design can get (design patent) and which not. Some information on the proceedings for trademarks and patents, advantages and disadvantages, etc. would help too.